# Does bash import variables from inner file at second and deeper levels?

Tags: bash

I have these files:

```
# ~/.bashrc


# I expect that variables in that file will be exported 
. ~/env_vars.sh
```

```
# ~/env_vars.sh

# I expect it expands parent's vars
export VAR=test
```

What happens when I run bash:

```
$ echo $VAR
$
```

Nothing.

but when I place my variables directly in `.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc
VAR=test
```

Then it works:

```
$ echo $VAR
test
```

Is it possible to import variables from inner files?

About versions:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

$ uname -a
Linux user-pc 4.9.38-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jul 15 12:04:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I do know that `~` works and `~/env_vars.sh` have sourced:

```
# ~/env_vars.sh
touch ~/env_sourced.test
```

```
$ bash
$ file ~/env_sourced.test
~/env_sourced.test: empty
```

Comment: The above works on my machine.  What version of bash?   You may want to try using `${HOME}` instead of `~`

Comment: Another question -- how do you startup bash?   If you start bash with the `sh` command, it does not automatically read the `.bashrc` file...

Comment: One last thing, check for hidden characters in your `. ~/.env_vars.sh` line...

Comment: In a login shell the `.bashrc` is usually loaded through the `.bash_profile` which has to source it. Make sure your `.bash_profile` does so.

Comment: @John, `~` works perfectly, I know exactly that `~/env_var` is sourced every time

Comment: @John, I do run it with bash

Comment: @Aaron, I  do know that .bashrc have sourced.

Comment: @John, no hidden characters, only spaces and ascii

Comment: Weird. No idea personally. You might have more chance to get a solution on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree with @Aaron, very weird.  You can add `echo "VAR is $VAR" >> ~/env_sourced.test` into env_vars.sh, and to .bashrc (after the source) to eliminate the possibility that it's not being set properly or if it's being overwritten, but outside of that, what you described should work...